# Search queried data in google itself based on URL

Tags: google-custom-search, google-developers-console

I want to query on google search engine. Currently it provides weird search results. Which URL should I use below?

[image: See Current Setup of CSE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take two steps to search Google itself with your CSE.

1. In the top right of the area you circled, where it says "Search only included sites", click the drop down and select the other option. That option should say "Search the entire web but emphasize included sites".
2. Delete your current included sites.

That way you will be able to search all of Google with your CSE.

Comment: Yes I have included in my CSE.. http://search.lookdemo.biz/ .Your soultion provided me great help ... thanks

Comment: @HasmukhMistry I am happy to help :) Be sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark